# python: pyQT QApplication QwebPage instance to scrape javascript - how to completely destroy and reinitialize

Tags: python, pyqt, initialization, instance

I am using Scrapy (python) to scrape webpages generated at runtime with JavaScript. There are a number of options to do so, including dockerized middlewares such as Splash, Selenium and more.

I have howewer decided to tackle this problem by simply **running a PyQT instance (with .QWebPage() ), which has a WebKit interpreter and can therefore parse .js**

Given the scale of the pages to crawl, i want to run a number of jobs sequentially and completely reinitialize PyQT between them. Howewer, I cannot seem to be able to reinitialize PyQT completely!

The code is complex, but I seem to have the same problem with this straightforward, self-contained example I lifted from a fellow StackOverflower: ;)

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit
import sys

class PyQTRenderer(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.myApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    def loadpage(self, url):
        page = QtWebKit.QWebPage()
        loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()
        page.mainFrame().loadFinished.connect(loop.quit)
        page.mainFrame().load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        loop.exec_()
        return page.mainFrame().toHtml().toAscii()

    def close(self):
        print("exiting app")
        self.myApp.closeAllWindows()
        self.myApp.exit()
    # something else maybe???


myRenderer = PyQTRenderer()
print myRenderer.loadpage('https://google.com')[1:100], " google"
print myRenderer.loadpage('https://bing.com')[1:100], " bing"
myRenderer.close()

myRenderer2 = PyQTRenderer()
print myRenderer2.loadpage('http://wikipedia.org')[1:100], "wikipedia (fails)"
myRenderer2.close()
```

the expected output should be

```
!DOCTYPE html><html itemscope  google
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C/  bing
!DOCTYPE html><html lang="mul wikipedia
```

instead I get:

```
!DOCTYPE html><html itemscope  google
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C/  bing
<html><head></head>< wikipedia (fails)
```

if I try to use del(myRenderer), myRenderer2 throws a bunch of errors about not being able to connect to a number of QTApp network processes. It seems therefore that *closeAllWindows()* and *exit()* do not work as I'd think they would, and that the underlying pyQT libraries keep running in the background.

My question: how can I completely reinitialize PyQT in order to be able to instantiate different PyQTRenderer() sequentially?

Thanks in advance!

edit: myApp.quit() is also not a possible solution - at least in the current implementation - as all it does in my code is crashing the main python process.